# Custom animation of colletion

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

There are two types of animation that I must to do:

- http://www.gifti.me/i/KGSVP.gif
- http://www.gifti.me/i/9ojLapD.gif

Any idea how to do this? It seems that simple transition animations aren't helpful in this case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve the first animation by starting a Storyboard when the GridViewItem is loaded (either by retemplating the control or in an ItemTemplate underneath the control).  See my answer to this question:
[Animation when add or remove item from GridView XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156165/animation-when-add-or-remove-item-from-gridview-xaml/18166132#18166132)

For the second animation, looks like you first want to run some translation and skew transform animation on the entire GridView when it gets loaded, but then run a separate scale animation on each column.  For the scale animation, you could detect which cells are in which column, build the animation into the GridViewItem or ItemTemplate, and run those animations manually.  This is probably the best way to do it if you don't know how many items will be in each column (e.g. because form factor may change).  Otherwise perhaps you could use grouping and run a scale animation on each group.

Comment: About second animation: what if gridview contains a lot of items?

Comment: You just have to run the animation on the items initially on screen.  There are probably a few ways to figure this out, but no immediately available property for it.  If you are using explicit sizes it's easy; otherwise you can listen to SizeChanged events to get sizes after layout has first run.  If you are grouping, running animations on the groups should be easy.  I wouldn't worry too much about perf here since from the gif provided you shouldn't have too many items on screen at a time.

Comment: In reality, there can be over thousands items in collection. That's just and example.

Comment: I don't think it matters how many items are in the collection.  Use a virtualizing panel and just run the animation on the containers that are on the screen.  Say that you have 10k items but only 20 items will be shown in the viewport on screen when the GridView initially loads - just run the animation on the 20 containers that host those initial 20 items.

Answer (score 0):

In code, you can try that:

```
DoubleAnimation a = new DaoubleAnimation();
a.From = 50;
a.To = 100;
a.BeginTime = "0:0:2";

b.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, a);
```

Comment: I know how to animate one button. I don't know how to animate group of UI items in sequence.

Comment: Ok. You may need a kind of scheduler for that maybe.

Comment: Maybe you can enter a begintime

Comment: Yeah, scheduler. But how? The are problem: I don't know how to make elements have size=0.0 at begin. Current solution looks after start like this: render all collection, disappear all collection, try to animate elements each by each